# Library for Jacobi eigenvalue algorithm

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I am looking for a C or C++ or fortran library that implements the Jacobi eigenvalue algorithm:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_eigenvalue_algorithm

do you know if it is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SelfAdjointEigenSolver of eigen (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) uses the Jacobi algorithm.

Comment: thanks! better to use 3.0.4 or 3.1.0 alpha?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.netlib.org/misc/syevj) contains a [shell archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shar) of a bunch of FORTRAN routines implementing a version of the Jacobi method, due to Ivan Slapničar. See [this paper](http://www.fernuni-hagen.de/MATHPHYS/veselic/downloads/slap.pdf) for details on the algorithm.